# How do I find the overlapping area between two arbitrary polygons

Tags: java, graphics, computational-geometry

I'm trying to create a method that will take in two arbitrary lists of nodes, for a subject and a clipping polygon, and output either:

> a) the area of the overlap
>   b) a list of nodes for the resulting (clipped) polygon so that I can calculate the area

I've found lots of examples which clip an arbitrary polygon using a rectangular window (which is fairly standard in graphics) but that's not what I need. I understand that it's fairly complex, particularly when you get holes, convex polygons and the like. The only simplifying assumption which I can make is that the arbitrary polygons will not contain any holes.

I'm not at all an expert in this field, so would something like the Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm work? Are there any libraries out there which already do this, or is my best bet to simply implement the algorithm as described in pseudo-code on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Err... That algorithm wouldn't handle concave clipping polygones correctly, right?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that using the [JavaGeom](http://geom-java.sourceforge.net/) library worked very well. It integrates the code from the Java port of GPC (which is no longer available) and thus allows arbitrary polygon operations. Using SimplePolygon2D and Polygon2DUtils.intersection() I was able to get the desired operation.

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any libraries out there which already do this ...

Polygon clipping is a complex task. I wouldn't recommend trying to do it yourself unless you want to spend many months on it.
Wikipedia lists a number of clipping libraries (and IIRC in that list only Clipper is free for use in commercial applications):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons#External_links

ps: I admit to a personal bias for Clipper since I'm the author :)
More info here: http://angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [Weiler-Atherton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler%E2%80%93Atherton) is the one you need:

> The algorithm requires polygons to be
>   clockwise and not reentrant (self
>   intersecting). The algorithm can
>   support holes (as counter-clockwise
>   polygons wholly inside their parent
>   polygon), but requires additional
>   algorithms to decide which polygons
>   are holes.

Your polygons fit those criteria, right?
I don't know about implementations, but it sounds like you would be better off implementing W-A than S-H if either of your polygons could be concave.

Answer (score 1):

Try [gpc](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/).

Comment: I had found GPC, but the Java port seems to be down (dead-link).

Comment: Java port link appears to be up now: http://sourceforge.net/projects/geom-java/files/gpcj/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a lot of different libraries and the one that worked best was the [JTS Topological Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) which is pure Java and LGPL2 licensed.