# How to calculate intercepting area of polygons in python

Tags: python, arrays, polygon, intersection

I have multiple 2D polygons (with solid color) coordinates as a numpy array which are lying on top of each other. I want to calculate the visible are of each polygon.

Example:

```
    polygon1 = np.array([[0, 461],[1919, 512],[1919, 0],[0, 0]])
    polygon2 = np.array([[0, 420],[ 437, 380],[1057, 350],[1572, 347],[1919, 405],[1919, 639],[0, 639]])
```

Some part of polygon2 lies on first polygon. How to calculate the total visible area of polygon1 or area of intersection ?

Comment: This sounds like a mathematics problem

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229425/how-do-i-find-the-overlapping-area-between-two-arbitrary-polygons

Comment: The Shapely module (https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might be interesting; it has functions for computing intersections between 2d shapes (including nasty cases like non-convex polygons with holes).

Comment: This seems like intersecting rows across two 2D numpy arrays :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate overlapped area between two rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152904/calculate-overlapped-area-between-two-rectangles)

Answer (score 4):

I want to pre-face my answer by stating that I am confused as to what exactly you are looking for, but you mentioned calculating the area of intersection.

```py
# Import shapely dependencies 
from shapely import geometry, ops

# Polygons - no need for arrays; but if need be, you can use them instead 

polygon1 = geometry.Polygon(((0, 461),(1919, 512),(1919, 0),(0, 0)))
polygon2 = geometry.Polygon(((0, 420), (437, 380), (1057, 350),(1572, 347), (1919, 405), (1919, 639),(0, 639)))

polygon1.intersection(polygon2).area
```

Obviously, you would have to first install shapely. If for some reason this is not what you want, but you want to find the area of the union - use:

```py
multipoly = geometry.MultiPolygon(polygons = (polygon1, polygon2))
ops.unary_union(multipoly).area
```